# Notification callback in iOS when iTunes sync/file transfer is complete

Tags: itunes, ios5, synchronization, filesystemwatcher

I have searched for how to receive callbacks in iOS5 when the file system has changed. I've found the following sample from Apple's site, but it only notifies the given delegate when a file is removed/created.

> DirectoryWatcher class in the DocInteraction sample app
>
> http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/DocInteraction/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010052

Is there an API call that I can make to receive a "sync is complete" callback event? Note, a user might transfer large files and I need to know when the transfer is complete. Also, in iOS5, iTunes sync can occur in the background, meaning that your application doesn't necessarily leave the foreground; hence this method is not called:

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I took the DirectoryWatcher code and made some modifications to poll the file sizes. https://github.com/hwaxxer/MHDirectoryWatcher