# NSBundleDidLoadNotification: iTunes File Sharing feature

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsnotificationcenter, nsbundle

How do I get to trigger the NSBundleDidLoadNotification notification?

The app, i'm working on, uses iTunes File Sharing feature. The app shares only **.bundle** files. The bundle contains some kind of xml and movie files.

The goal is to get notified **after the bundle is completely uploaded.**

see my earlier post [iTunes File Sharing app: realtime monitoring for incoming datas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9731521/itunes-file-sharing-app-realtime-monitoring-for-incoming-datas)